# Some error(s) occurred while processing annotations

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

When I add the code int activity

```
 @Inject
 lateinit var mCommonService:CommonService
```

The error comes

> e: Error: Can't access Nullable
>
> e:   Can't find javax.annotation.Nullable
>
> e:   For details, please refer to the following stacktrace.
>
> w: Warning: These options aren't used by any annotation processors:'[kapt.kotlin.generated]'
>
> e: Some error(s) occurred while processing annotations. Please see the error messages above.

this is my module build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-rxjava2-adapter:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.8.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.8.0'
    compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.0.1'
    compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.11'
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.11'
    compile 'com.readystatesoftware.systembartint:systembartint:1.0.3'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
    compile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.5.1'
//    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:26.0.0-alpha1'
    kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:$rootProject.ext.gradle_version"
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

This is my component

```
@ActivityScope
@Component(modules = arrayOf(CommonModule::class),dependencies = arrayOf(AppComponent::class))
interface CommonComponent {
     fun inject(activity: MainActivity)
}
```

This is my module

```
@Module
class CommonModule {

    @Singleton @Provides fun provideCommonService(retrofit: Retrofit): CommonService {
        return retrofit.create(CommonService::class.java)
    }
}
```

And this is my activity

```
    @Inject
    lateinit var mCommonService:CommonService// when i inject this,the error comes

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        getViewDataBinding(R.layout.activity_main)
         DaggerCommonComponent.builder()
                .appComponent(appComponent)
                .commonModule(CommonModule())
                .build()
                .inject(this)
 }
```

If I delete the inject code the program run correctly, I try add @JvmWildcard at CommomService @provides return type, but it still doesn't work

Comment: What do the characters next to `Nullable` say in your second snippet? Is that the full gradle console error message?

Comment: Please always remember Stack Overflow **is intended to be English only**. I've done the translate job for you for this time, but you'd better do it yourself the next time. @DavidRawson I've finished the translation.

Comment: What happens if you add `compile 'javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.2'` to your `build.gradle`?

Comment: Or `provided`..